# C: re-declaring with different type when all types are the same

Tags: c, header-files, redeclaration

I have a header file that contains this function declaration:

```
bool isAbelianGroup(ConstGroupMemberP IdentityElement, ConstGroupMemberP members[],
                const int membersLen, const binaryOp oper, const freeMember freeMember,
                const GroupComparator compare);
```

I have a c file in which I implement this function (copy-pasted the prototype from the declaration in the h file)

```
bool isAbelianGroup(ConstGroupMemberP IdentityElement, ConstGroupMemberP members[],
                const int membersLen, const binaryOp oper, const freeMember freeMember,
                const GroupComparator compare){...}
```

and yet, I get an error for re-declaring with different type:

[image]

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Don't post a screenshot, copy the error message as plain text and paste it here.

Comment: Cant copy from alt box

Comment: Check the order in which .h files are included.

Comment: Wild guess: there is a semicolon missing in one of your struct definitions. (there are plenty of these)

Comment: Is this just an Intellisense (or whatever your IDE calls it) error message or do you get an error when compiling as well?

Comment: Are they really the same ? Instead of posting the prototype from the declaration in the h file you should post the function header from the c file.

Comment: There is no semicolon missing in the struct definitions. This is the only error I get.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Both are posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:
I should have written 
`const freeMember freeFunc` in both h and c files instead of `const freeMember freeMember`.

That was hard to find.